# Find whether an interval falls within a set of intervals Python

Tags: python, search, set, intervals

I am using `python-intervals` from `portion` package in Python: `import portion as P`

To check whether an item is contained in a set, we can do `item in set`, for example `2 in {2,3}` gives `True`. (This takes O(1) time)

To check whether an interval is contained within another interval, we can do `item in interval`, for example `P.closed(2,3) in P.open(1,10)` gives `True`.

I would like to check whether an interval is contained in a list of intervals.
The iterative way (O(n)) to do it would be:

```
import portion as P

intervals_set = {P.open(1,10), P.open(20,30)}
item = P.closed(2,3)
result = []
for s in intervals_set:
    if item in s:
        result.append(item)
```

I have to perform the search for many items (run this for loop many times) for a long set of intervals, so I was wondering if there is an efficient way to find whether an interval exists in a set of intervals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of `portion`.

`portion` supports interval sets out of the box, so you don't need to manually create a set of intervals (e.g. no need for `{P.open(1,10), P.open(20,30)}`). Simply create a disjunction of these intervals, and it will work:

```py
interval = P.open(1, 10) | P.open(20, 30)
item = P.closed(2, 3)
assert item in interval
```

This will be slightly faster than the solution you propose, since `portion` internally sorts (disjunctions of) intervals, and benefits from this sorting to make things faster.

If you have many items, then the loop becomes:

```
for item in items: 
  if item in interval: 
    result.append(item)
```

Or, using list comprehensions, `[item for item in items if item in interval]`.